# The Tk path doesn't change color as expected

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

## Summary

My code identifies Tk buttons and then uses their position to see what the fastest route is from the start to the end using Dijkstra's algorithm.  Then that route gets colored in blue to shown to the user.

The problem is that when I specify any combination of buttons - simple or complex - it doesn't show the user the fastest route.

```
import sys
sys.tracebacklimit = 0
import tkinter as tk
import random as rd
import heapq


def dijkstra(graph, start, finish):
    # Initialize distances and predecessors
    distances = {node: float('infinity') for node in graph}
    distances[start] = 0
    predecessors = {node: None for node in graph}

    # Priority queue to store (distance, node) pairs
    priority_queue = [(0, start)]

    while priority_queue:
        current_distance, current_node = heapq.heappop(priority_queue)

        # Check if the current path is shorter than the stored distance
        if current_distance > distances[current_node]:
            continue

        for neighbor, weight in graph[current_node].items():
            distance = current_distance + weight

            # If a shorter path is found, update the distance and predecessor
            if distance < distances[neighbor]:
                distances[neighbor] = distance
                predecessors[neighbor] = current_node
                heapq.heappush(priority_queue, (distance, neighbor))
    for finish, distance in distances.items(): 
        sh= (f"la route la plus courte {start} vers {finish}: {distance}")
    for node, predecessor in predecessors.items():
        path = []
        current_node = node
        while current_node is not None:
            path.insert(0, current_node)
            current_node = predecessors[current_node]
        sh_pth=(f"la route la plus courte {start_node} vers {finish}: {' -> '.join(path)}")

    return distances, predecessors, sh,sh_pth,path

d1=1.675 #moyenne de largeur d'un vehicule
D1=14 #moyenne de largeur d'une roue
d2=4.875 #moyenne de longueur  d'un vehicule
D2=100 #longueur unitaire des routes choisi arbitrairement 
a=1 #distance moyenne entre deux vehicules par leurs cotes
b=5 # distance moyenne entre deux vehicules successives
#avec un petit calcul manuel on a trouve que le nb max moyen de vehicules est 52
def p(n):
    return(n*((d1+a)*(d2+b))/(D1*D2))

def end(btn):
    if btn.cget('background') != "yellow" and btn.cget('background') != "black":
        btn.configure(bg="blue")

def set_end(path):
    for k in range(len(path)):
        n = n+path[k]
        i, j = map(int, n.split('|'))
        end(buttons[i][j]) 

def status(btn):
    if btn.cget('background')==None:
        z=1
    elif btn.cget('background')=='yellow':
        return "yellow"
    elif btn.cget('background')=='green':
        return "green"
    elif btn.cget('background')=='black':
        return "black"
    elif btn.cget('background')=='orange':
        return "orange"
    elif btn.cget('background')=='red':
        return "red"

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")
window.title("Exemple")
icon = tk.PhotoImage(file='logo.png')
window.iconphoto(True,icon)
window.config(background='#26282b')
epsilon=-1
def click(button):
    global epsilon, start_node, finish_node
    epsilon = epsilon + 1
    colors = ["yellow", "green", "orange", "red", "black"]
    color = colors[epsilon % 5]
    button.config(bg=color)
    
    if color == "yellow":
        start_node = f"{button.grid_info()['row']}|{button.grid_info()['column']}"
    elif color == "black":
        finish_node = f"{button.grid_info()['row']}|{button.grid_info()['column']}"


buttons = [[None]*15 for _ in range(15)]
coefs = [[None]*15 for _ in range(15)]

for i in range(15):
    for j in range(15):
        buttons[i][j] = tk.Button(window, width=4, height=2, command=lambda i=i, j=j: click(buttons[i][j]))
        buttons[i][j].grid(row=i, column=j)

graph_node={
    '2|2': {},
    '14|14':{}
}
start_i=0
start_j=0
finish_i=0
finish_j=0


for i in range(15):
    for j in range(15):
            if status(buttons[i][j]) == "yellow":
                graph_node[str(i)+'|'+str(j)]={}
                start_node=str(i)+'|'+str(j)
                start_i=i
                start_j=j
            elif status(buttons[i][j]) == "green":
                coefs[i][j] = p(rd.randrange(1, 17))
                graph_node[str(i)+'|'+str(j)] = {}
                if i < 14:
                    graph_node[str(i)+'|'+str(j)][str(i+1)+'|'+str(j)] = coefs[i+1][j]
                if i > 0:
                    graph_node[str(i)+'|'+str(j)][str(i-1)+'|'+str(j)] = coefs[i-1][j]
                if j < 14:
                    graph_node[str(i)+'|'+str(j)][str(i)+'|'+str(j+1)] = coefs[i][j+1]
                if j > 0:
                    graph_node[str(i)+'|'+str(j)][str(i)+'|'+str(j-1)] = coefs[i][j-1]
            elif status(buttons[i][j]) == "orange":
                coefs[i][j]=p(rd.randrange(18,34))
                graph_node[str(i)+'|'+str(j)]={}
                if i < 14:
                    graph_node[str(i)+'|'+str(j)][str(i+1)+'|'+str(j)] = coefs[i+1][j]
                if i > 0:
                    graph_node[str(i)+'|'+str(j)][str(i-1)+'|'+str(j)] = coefs[i-1][j]
                if j < 14:
                    graph_node[str(i)+'|'+str(j)][str(i)+'|'+str(j+1)] = coefs[i][j+1]
                if j > 0:
                    graph_node[str(i)+'|'+str(j)][str(i)+'|'+str(j-1)] = coefs[i][j-1]
            elif status(buttons[i][j]) == "red":
                coefs[i][j]=p(rd.randrange(35,52))
                graph_node[str(i)+'|'+str(j)]={}
                if i < 14:
                    graph_node[str(i)+'|'+str(j)][str(i+1)+'|'+str(j)] = coefs[i+1][j]
                if i > 0:
                    graph_node[str(i)+'|'+str(j)][str(i-1)+'|'+str(j)] = coefs[i-1][j]
                if j < 14:
                    graph_node[str(i)+'|'+str(j)][str(i)+'|'+str(j+1)] = coefs[i][j+1]
                if j > 0:
                    graph_node[str(i)+'|'+str(j)][str(i)+'|'+str(j-1)] = coefs[i][j-1]
            elif status(buttons[i][j])== "black":
                graph_node[str(i)+'|'+str(j)]={}
                finish_node=str(i)+'|'+str(j)
                finish_i=i
                finish_j=j
            else:
                coefs[i][j]=10**100

"""for i in range(start_i, finish_i - 1):
    for j in range(start_j, finish_j - 1):
        graph_node[str(i)+'|'+str(j)][str(i+1)+'|'+str(j)]=coefs[i+1][j]
        graph_node[str(i)+'|'+str(j)][str(i-1)+'|'+str(j)]=coefs[i-1][j]
        graph_node[str(i)+'|'+str(j)][str(i)+'|'+str(j+1)]=coefs[i][j+1]
        graph_node[str(i)+'|'+str(j)][str(i)+'|'+str(j-1)]=coefs[i][j-1]"""

def calculate_and_highlight_path():
    distance, predecessors, sh_len, sh_pth, path = dijkstra(graph_node, start_node, finish_node)
    print(f"Path: {path}")
    n = start_node
    for k in range(len(path)):
        try:
            if path[k]:
                n = n + "|" + path[k]
                i, j = map(int, n.split('|'))
                print(f"i: {i}, j: {j}")
                if buttons[i][j].cget('background') not in ["black", "yellow"]:
                    buttons[i][j].config(bg="blue")
        except KeyError as e:
            print(f"KeyError: {e}, path: {path}, k: {k}, n: {n}")


e_btn = tk.Button(window, width=6, height=2, text='calculer', command=calculate_and_highlight_path)
e_btn.grid(row=0, column=18)



window.mainloop()
```

Comment: The two `for` loops in your `dijkstra` function create `sh` and `sh_pth` over and over, each one overwriting the previous one.  How is one supposed to use this?